# Multiple hook_menu_alter over-writing issue

Tags: routes

I want to customize my menu by using hook_menu_alter by over-writing another installed module, which also has a hook_menu_alter inside.

I check the procedure using xdebug, finding that drupal execute my hook_menu_alter first, and then the existing hook_menu_alter in that module. In this case all my alteration is being over-written. How can I reverse the order of execution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change the weight of the module in the systems table but doesn't always work and can cause other issues.  I would use the `hook_modules_implement_alter` function.  You will need to unset yours and then add yours to the top or before the other module.  Here is an example I used doing a `hook_user_delete` and `hook_user_insert`

```
function users_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
  if($hook == "user_insert" || $hook == "user_delete")
  {
    unset($implementations['user']);
    $user = array('users' => false);
    $implementations = $user + $implementations;
  }
}
```

Yours would be like this:

```
function users_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
  if($hook == "menu_alter")
  {
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $mymodule = array('mymodule' => false);
    $implementations = $mymodule + $implementations; // Also could use array_merge
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! hook_modules_implement_alter works great. But I do it slightly different. Since I want my module to over write other module, the last line is "$implementations = $implementations + $mymodule;"

Comment: Remember to make a note of that somewhere it'll be easily found, or someone will get really frustrated while trying to figure out why some hook implementations do not get called. ;)